# HTTP Function ends with code 16, documents not updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that returns the result correctly with: `response.send("Update Last Payments Completed");` but in the log it reports: and no documents are updated

> Error: Process exited with code 16

Here is my code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

/// Updates the last payment done in the neighbors documents
export const updateLastPaymentHTTP = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const neighbors = await admin.firestore().collection("neighbors").get();
      const promises = [];
      neighbors.forEach(async (neighbor) => {
        const topPayment = await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection(`neighbors/${neighbor.ref}/payments`)
          .orderBy("date", "desc")
          .limit(1)
          .get();
        topPayment.forEach(async (payment) => {
          if (payment.exists) {
            const lastPayment = payment.data().date;
            promises.push(neighbor.ref.update({ last_payment: lastPayment }));
          } else {
            promises.push(neighbor.ref.update({ last_payment: null }));
          }
        });
        await Promise.all(promises);
        response.send("Update Last Payments Completed");
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error Updating Last Payment and Debt ${error}`);
    }
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `response.send()` inside a loop.  That's almost certainly not what you want, as you can only send a single response, and then the function terminates.  Move the last `await` and `response.send()` **outside** the loop. to be executed only a single time after all the work is complete.

```
      neighbors.forEach(async (neighbor) => {
          // ...
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
      response.send("Update Last Payments Completed");
```

Comment: Ok I did that and it do resolve the Error code 16 but now I am getting again the `finished with status code: 304` error, anything else that I may be doing wrong with my function? Thanks!